# What's the purpose of the default Kubernetes service?

Tags: kubernetes

When you run: `kubectl get svc -n default`, you will have a Kubernetes service with Type as ClusterIP already there.

What is the purpose of this service? Are there some references?

I'm running in Minikube:

```
kubectl describe svc/kubernetes
```

Output:

```
Name:              kubernetes
Namespace:         default
Labels:            component=apiserver
               provider=kubernetes
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.0.0.1
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        8443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.0.2.15:8443
Session Affinity:  ClientIP
Events:            <none>
```

And:

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

Output:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.99.100:8443
```

Answer (score 21):

As far as I know, the Kubernetes service in the default namespace is a service which forwards requests to the Kubernetes master (typically Kubernetes API server).

So all the requests to the *kubernetes.default* service from the cluster will be routed to the configured endpoint IP address. In this scenario its Kubernetes master IP address.

For example:

Let’s check out the output of `kubectl describe svc kubernetes` and look at the the endpoint IP address.

[image]

Now let’s check our cluster information:

`kubectl cluster-info`

[image]

Please note that the Kubernetes master is running at the same IP address as the endpoint's IP address of the *kubernetes.default* service.

Comment: API Server is not a pod inside the cluster. As if we use the following command "kubectl get pods " we do not see any pods with the name of Kubernetes. Correct me If i am wrong

Comment: Thanks, Karthik. Mine is a little different from yours since Im running it in Minikube. The mysterious Endpoints is 10.0.2.15. It needs to point at API Server. How did it accomplish this?

Comment: Hi Suresh, yes you are right there will not be any pods with the name ```kubernetes```. So a service need not have to forward requests to the pod it can forward requests to a remote url also. That is the same thing done by kubernetes service in the default namespace. It forward requests to the kubernetes master.

Comment: if you are running on localhost (eg minikube or docker for mac) you can see and compare ip using `kubectl describe node/docker-for-desktop` for instance

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47525313/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance. (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).)

Answer (score 7):

It is so that every Pod within your cluster can make API requests of the Kubernetes master without having to hard-code the API URL therein. Your `~/.kube/config` may very well have the "external" address of your Kubernetes master, but it makes very little sense for API traffic to leave the cluster and then re-enter the cluster for a Pod that could be co-located on the same Node. Pods are able to use the [Service Account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) credentials injected by kubernetes, unless that Service Account feature is disabled per-Pod.

Your application is free to make use of that functionality, too, if it wishes -- for example -- to discover any annotations on its Pod, or how many other replicas there are in its Deployment, and so forth.

I guess the tl;dr is that for 90% of the Pods it doesn't matter, and for the remaining 10% it is **super** convenient.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. It appears that Pods use the Default ServiceAccount to communicate with APIServer if necessary.

Answer (score -2):

So this Kubernetes service by default uses the *kupe-apiserver* pod in the backend. If this goes down, we'll not be able to communicate with master, and [kubectl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes#API_clients) commands won’t work.

Comment: `kube-apiserver` is not a pod but a binary that's installed on the control-plane.  While your answer isn't completely wrong as far as I can tell the others are of far better quality.