# Cannot delete kubernetes service with no deployment

Tags: kubernetes, devops

I cannot force delete kubernetes service. However I don't have any deployments at the moment.

```
~$ kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   pod/etcd-kubernetes-master                      1/1     Running            0          26m
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-kubernetes-master            1/1     Running            0          26m
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-kubernetes-master   1/1     Running            0          26m
kube-system   pod/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-5h46j                 0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          26m
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-ltz4v                            1/1     Running            0          26m
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-kubernetes-master            1/1     Running            0          26m

NAMESPACE     NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP                  17m
kube-system   service/kube-dns     ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   48m

NAMESPACE     NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-amd64     1         1         0       1            0           <none>                   47m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm       0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   47m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm64     0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   47m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le   0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   47m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-s390x     0         0         0       0            0           <none>                   47m
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   48m


~$ kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces 
No resources found
```

Please help to stop and delete the kubernetes service

Comment: What exactly do you want to delete? By "service" -- do you mean some specific resource?

Comment: Can you add some logs? What problem do you face when you do `kubectl delete svc <svc_name>`

Comment: you want to delete the service that makes everything to talk to the api-server?

Comment: Why do you want deleting it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523136/whats-the-purpose-of-the-default-kubernetes-service sheds light on the service you'd like to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not mandatory to a have a deployment for pods. Generally, system pods running in `kube-system` namespace are created as [static pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/) directly.
You can delete a pod via `kubectl delete po podname` and deamonset via `kubectl delete ds daemonsetname` and a service via `kubectl delete svc servicename`

The services `kubernetes` and `kube-dns` in kube-system namespace are managed by kubernetes control plane and will be recreated automatically upon removal. Also I don't think you have a reason to delete those.

Answer (score 0):

The list which you posted are all core kubernetes services, these should not be deleted. If you have used `kubeadm` to create the kubernetes cluster, you can run `kubeadm reset` to destroy the cluster.

Comment: Try to remove finalizer field if it exist on the deployed service via kubectl edit service-name.
Once, this field is removed, the service will be automatically remove