# minikube: will deleting the service "service/kubernetes" break my kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-service

I accidentally did: `k delete service/kubernetes`. it sounds like an essential service... so i would think deleting would break the kubernetes cluster but somehow the service just came back.

#### will deleting the service "service/kubernetes" break my kubernetes cluster? if no why?

related question: what causes the service `service/kubernetes` to come back automatically?

Comment: Short answer, yes 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523136/whats-the-purpose-of-the-default-kubernetes-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what causes the service service/kubernetes to come back automatically?

A part of the control plane run controllers, and there is a controller that is responsible for the `kubernetes` Service. See [controlplane controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controlplane/controller.go)

Comment: RE your link to source code: i'm not familiar with the large code base of kubernetes. i'm also not fluent in `go`. can you provide a line number where? (i can update your link to be a specific commit so the line number always works).

Comment: You can follow the comments above each function, e.g. the "class" has this comment https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controlplane/controller.go#L47-L50 This controller continuously run, and this specific function is responsible for recreating the kubernetes service if it does not exists: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controlplane/controller.go#L209